# multiple, prioritized ways to satisfy a dependency

Tags: build-process, scons

Suppose I have target `A` that can be built only when either `B` or `C` have already been built. Building `C` is much more expensive than building `B`.

How can I write an optimal `SConstruct` file which satisfies the following constraints when I ask it to build `A`.

1. If either `B` or `C` is present and uptodate, directly build `A`
2. If neither `B` nor `C` is present and uptodate, first build `B` and then build `A`

If `scons` does not provide this capability, does any other build tool provide it?

Comment: If C is always so much more expensive to build than B, I'd seriously consider never building C at all. Make B the only dependency for A, and you should do fine, based on your description of the problem given above...

Comment: Of course there are other very important reasons to build C when I can wait. I can start working as soon as B is built. But I can only be sure that my work is correct when C is built.

Comment: Then your description is a bit misleading isn't it? You don't mention anywhere that you finally need to build with "C", in order to build a correct version of "A". Remember that SCons is all about delivering correct builds in the first place... Finally, how is the Build system supposed to know *when* exactly you want your final "A" (=use C) or when you still can start preliminary work based on an incorrect "A" (=use B)?

Comment: I intentionally removed details like this from my question. I still think that my question clearly describes WHAT I am looking for. The removed details and your questions are only concerned about the WHY aspect. Anyway, I have a separate target A' which is the "final A", which needs C

Comment: A more detailed version of the question can be found at: stackoverflow.com/revisions/34243938/2 This version also explains my motivations for the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using SideEffect() on the builder for B or C, and also have a builder to generate A.

Haven't tried this, but it might work.